# Multi-Monitor Support for incoming Remote Connections (Windows to Mac)

Tags: macos, windows, monterey, remote-desktop

I've currently got a Windows PC, and use it to RDP to a Windows laptop. When I do this, it passes through the multiple monitors from the host and lets me use them within the RDP session. In this way, I can use up to 4 monitors on my laptop without needing to futz around with KVMs and extra cables.

This is the physical setup.

```
Host Machine (Windows 11)    --RDP->   Target Laptop (Windows 11)
 |     |     |     |                        |
 M1    M2    M3    M4                       M5 (integrated)
```

With this setup, I am able to use M1-M4 as separate monitors within the RDP session.

---

I'd like to do the same with a Mac laptop, but I'm struggling to work out how. From what I can see, RDP is not supported on Mac, and the alternative (VNC viewer) does work but doesn't seem to support the use of multi-monitors from the host (just when they are connected to the target machine).

```
Host Machine (Windows 11)    --RDP->   Target Laptop (MacOS Monterey 12.6)
 |     |     |     |                        |
 M1    M2    M3    M4                       M1 (integrated)
```

Is there any way to replicate this setup when connecting from Windows to Mac?